In a monoidal category, does every diagram involving she coherences commute?
The nlab cautions that not every diagram built from $\alpha, \lambda, \rho$ will comute, since it may be using equalities that are not solely dependent on the formal structure. I'm wondering if there is an example of this.
That same nlab page and this answer mention Isbell's example. However it seems that this only shows that there's no cartesian monoidal structure on the skeleton of $Set$ such that $\alpha$ is $id$. In order for this to be an example, we would need to show that there is at least one cartesian monoidal structure on the skeleton of $Set$. Is this the case? If not, are there any other examples?

What do you mean? It's an example of a diagram built from $\alpha$ that does not commute (namely the diagram with a single self-loop $\alpha$ on $D \times D \times D$). Of course the skeletal version of $\mathbf{Set}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$, so it is cartesian monoidal.

@NaïmFavier I'm having trouble with the second part of what you said. Is being cartesian monoidal preserved along equivalences? The obvious attempt of defining, say, $\alpha$ in $C$ as the image of $\alpha$ in $D$ for two equivalent categories $C$ and $D$ doesn't work.

"Being cartesian monoidal" just means having finite limits, so of course it is preserved by equivalence of categories. The associator is defined in terms of the universal property of the product. You can also transport the cartesian monoidal structure on $C$ to $D$ across the equivalence; you should get a monoidal structure equivalent to the cartesian one.

@NaïmFavier Oh I was missing that the associator and unitors were given by the cartesian universal property, thanks! You can write that as an answer and I'll accept it.
